Execute a Oracle query providing a parameter
My query takes a parameter and needs to be executed for all values coming from a table. How do I call my query? Please help.
Query to execute:
select &&pnbr, pname from PERSON where pno=&&pnbr;
Query to give all values for parameter:
select distinct personnbr from CUSTOMER

Code you posted suggests that you use SQL*Plus (because of the substitution variable).
However, do you really need that parameter? Because, the 1st query has to return some rows for values returned by the 2nd query. So - why don't take a different approach? Here are a few of them.
select distinct p.pnbr, p.pname
from person p join customer c on c.personnbr = p.pnbr

or
select p.pnbr, p.pname
from person p
where p.pnbr in (select c.personnbr 
                 from customer c)

or anonymous PL/SQL block
declare
  l_pname person.pname%type;
begin
  for cur_r in (select distinct c.personnbr from customer c) loop
    select p.pname
      into l_pname
    from person p
    where p.pnbr = cur_r.personnbr;

    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.personnbr ||' - '|| l_pname);
  end loop;
end;
/

or function that returns refcursor
create or replace function f_person return sys_refcursor is
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc for select p.pnbr, p.pname
                from person p
                where p.pnbr in (select c.personnbr
                                 from customer c);
  return l_rc;
end;
/

select f_person from dual;


I don't think that you can do what you asked for in pure SQL (meaning: let the 2nd query return some values, and - somehow - use them automatically as parameters in the 1st query).

Thank you for the quick reply. Actually my "to be executed query is huge using the parameter many time within it. I just gave a sample of the query here", hence seeking help with this team.
